# How to redirect user to external link using gRPC

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I want to ask if i can redirect user to external `url` using `gRPC` something similar to

```js
res.redirect('/ap1')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that functionality does not exist in gRPC.